# Multiplying values of 2 input fields in 3rd input field within a for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm having a slight problem. I have a **For Loop** with which I'm creating multiple 3 input fields *(Quantity, Rate, Price)*. I'm using **Javascript** function to get the Id of **'Quantity'** & **'Rate'** and show the **Product** in 3rd input **'Price'**. My problem is that in the for loop, I get the product of 1st record only by using Id & the rest of the 'Price' inputs do not catch the Product of their respective 'Quantity' & 'Rate' inputs. How do I manage to get this working with multiple 3 inputs? Please help me, I shall be very thankful.

**See Input Entry Image Here**

[image: See Input Entry Image Here]

**HTML Code:**

```
<?php
    $total = $total_entries;
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="item">Item</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="item[]">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                <input id="quantity" type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity[]">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="rate">Rate</label>
                <input id="rate" type="text" class="form-control" name="rate[]">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <input id="price" type="number" class="form-control" name="price[]">
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript Function:**

```
<script>
    $('#quantity, #rate').change(function(){
        var rate = parseFloat($('#quantity').val()) || 0;
        var box = parseFloat($('#rate').val()) || 0;
        $('#price').val(rate * box);    
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ID (#quantity) will work for single instance, you should try using class (.quantity) instead of ID (#quantity).

Comment: Yes it works for 1 instance while using ID, if i use Class then the same Product gets displayed in all the Price inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php
    $total = $total_entries;
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="item">Item</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control item" name="item[<?php echo $i; ?>]">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                <input id="quantity_<?php echo $i; ?>" type="number" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[<?php echo $i; ?>]">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="rate">Rate</label>
                <input id="rate_<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text" class="form-control rate" name="rate[<?php echo $i; ?>]">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <input id="price_<?php echo $i; ?>" type="number" class="form-control price" name="price[<?php echo $i; ?>]">
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript function :

```
<script>
    $('.quantity, .rate').change(function(){
        var rate = parseFloat($(this).closest(".row").find(".quantity").val()) || 0;
        var box = parseFloat($(this).closest(".row").find(".rate").val()) || 0;
        $(this).closest(".row").find(".price").val(rate * box);    
    });
</script>
```

You were using common id for multiple elements, so it will consider only one element rather than considering required elements,

`Class` is to identify similar elements.

`Id` is an identifier to uniquely identify elements.

Comment: Thank U sooo much, u really helped me alot :)